# how to know the controller initiating the request in after_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application there are multiple controllers/actions that can modify the same model. I need to log  that an update was made and need to also log which action/controller initiated the request. Is is possible to do so in the after_update instead of within every action that makes an update?
I'm using Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `after_update` belongs to the model level, it does not have access to the controller.

At least you can use `after_update` to write in the log : when you will want to see on which controller it happen, you can browse the log to find the controller on the lines above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a separate application/service that does the loging, I'm actually sending requests to that service instead of logging it into Rails logs so this is not an option for me. There is a way to do so in the views http://www.postal-code.com/mrhappy/blog/2007/01/18/rails-knowing-the-current-action-in-a-view/ so I was wondering if there is a similar way for the models

Comment: No there is not, you have access to request params (where the actual controller is stored) in the controller / view level but not on the model. With your setup, you may add a `before_filter` in the controller which add a line into your log to make it working as I suggest in my answer..

Comment: With more research I'm now convinced : ) There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726136/identify-which-action-is-being-called-inside-a-model-ruby-on-rails. Thanks